# Weird double arithmetics in R

Tags: r, math, double

To reproduce:

```r
> 1 - 0.9 - 0.1
[1] -2.775558e-17
> 1 - 0.1 - 0.9
[1] 0
> 1 + (-0.9 -0.1)
[1] 0
> 1 + -0.9 + -0.1
[1] -2.775558e-17
> 1 + (-0.9 + -0.1)
[1] 0
> - 0.9 - 0.1 + 1
[1] 0
> - 0.9 + 1 - 0.1
[1] -2.775558e-17
> - 0.9 + (1 - 0.1)
[1] 0
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Add. info:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: operator precedence?  For me `1 - (0.9 +0.1)` or `1 -( 0.1 + 0.9)` both gives 0

Comment: Once you know that `1 - 0.9` is not `1.0` (but `1 - 0.1` is `0.9`) the results make sense.